# Summary of representative monthly sales in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

The goal of the request is to obtain a table of the monthly sales of every representative for the last 3 years.
It should looks like this:

| SELLER_ID | SELLER | MONTH | 2023 | 2022 | 2021 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0001 | JohnSmith | January | 0 | 2400 | 1987.34 |
| 0001 | JohnSmith | February | 2219.17 | 2000.01 | 2211.12 |
| 0001 | JohnSmith | March | 1983.62 | 2173.02 | 2002.27 |
| 0001 | JohnSmith | April | 1748.21 | 1943.21 | 2203.82 |
| 0001 | JohnSmith | May | 2083.62 | 2073.77 | 2101.39 |
| 0002 | JaneSmith | January | 1684.02 | 2400 | 1987.34 |
| 0002 | JaneSmith | February | 2419.17 | 1900.01 | 2221.12 |
| 0002 | JaneSmith | March | 1883.62 | 2273.02 | 2012.27 |

First, basic SQL request is like:

```sql
select c.SELLER_ID, r.NAME as SELLER,
       extract(year from c.DATE) as YEAR,
       to_char(c.DATE, 'YYYY-MM') as MONTH,
       to_char(c.DATE, 'Month') as MONTH_NAME,
       sum(c.S_TOTAL) as MONTHLY_TOTAL
  from SALE_HEADER c,
       SALER r
 where c.SELLER_ID=r.ID
   and extract(year from c.DATE) between extract(year from sysdate) -2 and extract(year from sysdate)
 group by SELLER_ID, r.NAME, extract(year from c.DATE), to_char(c.DATE, 'YYYY-MM'), to_char(c.DATE, 'Month'))
 order by SELLER_ID, to_char(c.DATE, 'YYYY-MM')
```

Which returns something like:

| SALER_ID | SALER | YEAR | MONTH | MONTH_NAME | MONTHLY_TOTAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0001 | JohnSmith | 2022 | 2022-02 | February | 2000.01 |
| 0001 | JohnSmith | 2023 | 2023-02 | February | 2219.17 |

Then using it as a subquery in this pivot query:

```sql
select SELLECR_ID, SELLER, substr(MONTH, 6,2) as MONTH, MONTH_NAME, "2021", "2022", "2023" from (
  -- preceding query as a subquery
)
pivot (
  sum(MONTHLY_TOTAL)
  for YEAR in (
    2021,
    2022,
    2023
  )
)
group by SELLER_ID, SELLER, substr(MONTH, 6,2), MONTH_NAME, "2021", "2022", "2023"
order by SELLER_ID, substr(MONTH, 6,2)
```

which returns data on separate lines like:

| SALER_ID | SALER | MONTH | MONTH_NAME | 2023 | 2022 | 2021 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0001 | JohnSmith | 02 | February |  | 2000.01 |  |
| 0001 | JohnSmith | 02 | February | 2219.17 |  |  |

So why are these 2 lines not on 1 line ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by MT0, this was a problem of aggregation.

I ended up with the following core request:

```sql
  select c.SELLER_ID, r.NAME as SELLER,
         extract(year from c.DATE) as YEAR,
         extract(month from c.DATE) as MONTH,
         to_char(extract(month from c.DATE), 'Month') as MONTH_NAME,
        sum(c.S_TOTAL) as MONTHLY_TOTAL
    from SALE c,
         SELLER r
   where c.SELLER_ID=r.ID
     and extract(year from c.DATE) between extract(year from sysdate) -2 and extract(year from sysdate)
   group by SELLER_ID, r.NAME, extract(month from c.DATE), to_char(extract(month from c.DATE), 'Month') ,
         extract(year from c.DATE)
   order by c.SELLER_ID, to_char(c.DATE, 'YYYY-MM')
```

Answer (score 1):

> So why are these 2 lines not on 1 line?

Because you aggregate by both month and year.

---

You can aggregate by month and then use conditional aggregation to get the year data for the months:

```sql
SELECT c.seller_id,
       MAX(s.name) as seller,
       TO_CHAR(c."DATE", 'MM') AS month,
       TO_CHAR(c."DATE", 'Month') AS month_name,
       SUM(
         CASE
         WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM c."DATE") = 2023
         THEN c.s_total
         END
       ) AS "2023",
       SUM(
         CASE
         WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM c."DATE") = 2022
         THEN c.s_total
         END
       ) AS "2022",
       SUM(
         CASE
         WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM c."DATE") = 2021
         THEN c.s_total
         END
       ) AS "2021"
FROM   sale_header c
       INNER JOIN saler s
       ON c.SELLER_ID=r.ID
WHERE  c."DATE" >= DATE '2021-01-01'
AND    c."DATE" <  DATE '2024-01-01'
GROUP BY
       c.seller_id,
       TO_CHAR(c."DATE", 'MM'),
       TO_CHAR(c."DATE", 'Month')
```

or:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT c.seller_id,
         s.name as seller,
         TO_CHAR(c."DATE", 'MM') AS month,
         TO_CHAR(c."DATE", 'Month') AS month_name,
         EXTRACT(YEAR FROM c."DATE") AS year,
         c.s_total
  FROM   sale_header c
         INNER JOIN saler s
         ON c.SELLER_ID=s.ID
  WHERE  c."DATE" >= DATE '2021-01-01'
  AND    c."DATE" <  DATE '2024-01-01'
)
PIVOT (
  SUM(s_total)
  FOR year IN (
    2023 AS "2023",
    2022 AS "2022",
    2021 AS "2021"
  )
)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE sale_header (seller_id, "DATE", s_total) AS
SELECT '0001', DATE '2023-01-01',  900 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '0001', DATE '2023-02-01',  800 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '0001', DATE '2023-03-01',  700 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '0001', DATE '2022-01-01',  600 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '0001', DATE '2022-02-01',  500 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '0001', DATE '2022-01-01',  400 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '0001', DATE '2022-03-01',  300 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '0001', DATE '2021-01-01',  200 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '0001', DATE '2021-02-01',  100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '0001', DATE '2021-03-01',    0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '0002', DATE '2023-01-01', 9000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '0002', DATE '2023-02-01', 8000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '0002', DATE '2023-03-01', 7000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '0002', DATE '2022-01-01', 6000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '0002', DATE '2022-02-01', 5000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '0002', DATE '2022-01-01', 4000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '0002', DATE '2022-03-01', 3000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '0002', DATE '2021-01-01', 2000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '0002', DATE '2021-02-01', 1000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '0002', DATE '2021-03-01',  999 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE saler (id, name) AS
  SELECT '0001', 'JohnSmith' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '0002', 'JaneSmith' FROM DUAL;
```

Both output:

| SELLER_ID | SELLER | MONTH | MONTH_NAME | 2023 | 2022 | 2021 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0001 | JohnSmith | 01 | January | 900 | 1000 | 200 |
| 0001 | JohnSmith | 02 | February | 800 | 500 | 100 |
| 0001 | JohnSmith | 03 | March | 700 | 300 | 0 |
| 0002 | JaneSmith | 01 | January | 9000 | 10000 | 2000 |
| 0002 | JaneSmith | 02 | February | 8000 | 5000 | 1000 |
| 0002 | JaneSmith | 03 | March | 7000 | 3000 | 999 |

or:

```sql
SELECT c.seller_id,
       MAX(s.name) as seller,
       TO_CHAR(c."DATE", 'MM') AS month,
       TO_CHAR(c."DATE", 'Month') AS month_name,
       SUM(
         CASE
         WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM c."DATE") = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE)
         THEN c.s_total
         END
       ) AS current_year,
       SUM(
         CASE
         WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM c."DATE") = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE) - 1
         THEN c.s_total
         END
       ) AS previous_year,
       SUM(
         CASE
         WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM c."DATE") = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE) - 2
         THEN c.s_total
         END
       ) AS previous_year_2
FROM   sale_header c
       INNER JOIN saler s
       ON c.SELLER_ID=s.ID
WHERE  c."DATE" >= ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'YY'), -24)
AND    c."DATE" <  ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'YY'), +12)
GROUP BY
       c.seller_id,
       TO_CHAR(c."DATE", 'MM'),
       TO_CHAR(c."DATE", 'Month')
```

or

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT c.seller_id,
         s.name as seller,
         TO_CHAR(c."DATE", 'MM') AS month,
         TO_CHAR(c."DATE", 'Month') AS month_name,
         EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE) - EXTRACT(YEAR FROM c."DATE") AS year_diff,
         c.s_total
  FROM   sale_header c
         INNER JOIN saler s
         ON c.SELLER_ID=s.ID
  WHERE  c."DATE" >= ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'YY'), -24)
  AND    c."DATE" <  ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'YY'), +12)
)
PIVOT (
  SUM(s_total)
  FOR year_diff IN (
    0 AS current_year,
    1 AS previous_year1,
    2 AS previous_year2
  )
)
```

Both output:

| SELLER_ID | SELLER | MONTH | MONTH_NAME | CURRENT_YEAR | PREVIOUS_YEAR | PREVIOUS_YEAR_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0001 | JohnSmith | 01 | January | 900 | 1000 | 200 |
| 0001 | JohnSmith | 02 | February | 800 | 500 | 100 |
| 0001 | JohnSmith | 03 | March | 700 | 300 | 0 |
| 0002 | JaneSmith | 01 | January | 9000 | 10000 | 2000 |
| 0002 | JaneSmith | 02 | February | 8000 | 5000 | 1000 |
| 0002 | JaneSmith | 03 | March | 7000 | 3000 | 999 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/pg9tmxQZ)

Comment: I've ended with the same conclusion and fixed it quite simply. Thank you for your time about this. I'll add my solution below.